# Do I need to implement OpenID as well as OAuth 2 to provide OAuth-style API authentication and authorisation?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, openid, dotnetopenauth

We're building a new app that requires access to specific customer data, and OAuth appears to be absolutely perfect for our requirements - long-lived access tokens, ability to grant access to specific resources or scopes, and so on. We are **not** looking for 'log in with Facebook' type capabilities here; we want to expose a single, specific OAuth authentication server based on our existing customer login database, and allow web and native apps to authenticate users via this endpoint.

I've been looking at the DotNetOpenAuth code samples, and it appears that all of the OAuth 2 examples use OpenID to perform the initial authentication and then use OAuth to actually authorise access to resources.

My understanding is that you can use a 'no-op authorisation' to perform the initial authentication, allowing you to use OAuth2 for the whole process; since we don't want to support federated authentication, OpenID doesn't actually offer anything, and so I'd rather stick to a single protocol for simplicity if possible.

Is there a good example anywhere of a pure OAuth2 authentication server built using .NET? Have I misunderstood the example code supplied with DotNetOpenAuth? Or is OpenID still required for the initial authentication phase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no coupled relation between OAuth2.0 and OpenId.
You can implement your custom login strategy in your OAuth2.0 implementation.

Since you gonna be the "Resource Owner"(as far as I understood your application owns the user base), you can simply replace in the DNOA authorization server sample the openid login with the standard asp.net login.

OAuth2.0 protocol simply needs to verify a user identity in order to emit an access token: how that identity will be verified is totally up to you.